# How to apply custom deserialization to DateTimeOffset field by System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json, datetimeoffset

How should I configure my deserializations to behave differently according to the data in json. When the time field contains an offset (like in the example `payload1`), I would like the deserialized object to have the offset as in the payload. And when the time field does not contain an offset (like in the example `payload2`) , I would like it to be interpreted as in UTC. In short I would like the below test to be successful. Would you please advise?

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public class TestObj
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("time")]
        public DateTimeOffset? Time { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        string payload1 = "{ \"time\": \"2022-03-17T07:31:00-04:00\" }";
        TestObj deserializedPayload1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestObj>(payload1);
        Assert.Equal("-04:00:00", deserializedPayload1.Time.Value.Offset.ToString());

        string payload2 = "{ \"time\": \"2022-03-17T07:31:00\" }";
        TestObj deserializedPayload2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestObj>(payload2);
        Assert.Equal("00:00:00", deserializedPayload2.Time.Value.Offset.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: This is doable with a custom converter (see [the GitHub issue tracking this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1566)), but FWIW, your interpretation would arguably be incorrect. According to the ISO 8601 spec (which defines that format), in absence of an offset or a `Z`, the value should be interpreted as *local time*.